# Yajra Ajax Datatables Including Dynamic URL with parameter

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I am using Yarja datatables for quite a complex table set and also have the ajax part returning two buttons:

```
        {
          $user = Auth::user();
          $cl = $user->client_id;
          $jb = DB::table('job')
          ->join('job_status', 'job.jobStatus_id', '=', 'job_status.id')
          ->join('customers', 'job.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
          ->join('users', 'job.operative_id', 'users.id')
          ->where('job.client_id', $cl)
          ->select(['job.id as id', 'job_status.status as status', 'job.customer_id as customer_id', 'customers.customer as customer', 'users.name as operative','job.address as address','job.postcode as postcode','job.slug as slug','job_status.id as jobStatusID'])
          ->get();
            return Datatables::of($jb)
             ->addColumn('action', function($pubs){
                             $btn = '<div style="float:right">
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" title="show details" style="margin-right:.5em;font-size:.75em"><i class="fas fa-book" ></i></a><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" title="show details" style="margin-right:.5em;font-size:.75em"><i class="fas fa-edit" ></i></a></div>';
                            return $btn;
                      })
              ->make(true);

        }
```

This works fine but now I want to add an action to the buttons, initially the edit, which is the route and the id of the row. 
As you can see I have replaced the # with the route so I have

```
"admin\jobView"
```

but I cannot seem to work out a way of adding a field from the query (specifically jb->id) so that the action would be something like

```
admin\jobView\123
```

Just can't seem to get it and would greatly appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pubs` should contain your job, so you should be able to use `$pubs->id`, to get the job id.

What I would do though is replace this giant string with a view so it becomes easier to maintain:

```
return Datatables::of($jb)
    ->addColumn('action', function($job) {
        return (string)view('admin.jobs.action', compact('job'));
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
```

Create a view, `admin/jobs/action.blade.php` for example:

```
<div style="float:right">
    <a href="{{ route('admin.jobview', $job->id) }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" title="show details" style="margin-right:.5em;font-size:.75em">
        <i class="fas fa-book"></i></a>
    <a href="{{ route('admin.jobview', $job->id) }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-xs" title="show details" style="margin-right:.5em;font-size:.75em">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Simple really. I just added the $pubs->id do the link now was <a href="/admin/jobView/'.$pubs->id.'" etc (single ' for the string). I will look at your other suggestion.